# Push XMM register to the stack

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, sse

Is there a way of pushing a packed doubleword integer from XMM register to the stack? and then later on pop it back when needed?

Ideally I am looking for something like PUSH or POP for general purpose registers, I have checked Intel manuals but I either missed the command or there isn't one...

Or will I have to unpack values to general registers and then push them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, there is no such a asm instruction under x86, but you can do something like:

```
//Push xmm0
sub     esp, 16
movdqu  dqword [esp], xmm0

//Pop xmm0
movdqu  xmm0, dqword [esp]
add     esp, 16
```

**EDIT:**

Upper code sample is direct push/pop emulation.

In case that you are using on stack also other local variables, than the `ebp` register must be at first properly set, like:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, LocaStackVariablesSize
//... your code
mov  esp, ebp
pop  ebp  
ret
```

In that case you can also use Daniels solution!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on that (your solution didn't exactly work) I came up with a working one (see my question). Still marked as answer...

Comment: @Daniel Gruszczyk: Yes you can use also ebp, but be sure that ebp register is properly set. Remember other push or call directives can overwrite your data on stack if ebp isn't set properly.

Comment: Might be worth editing the answer with what you eventually got to work, just to help future users who see this question.

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend to use a separate, 16-bit aligned stack for this purpose, so you can use movdqa instead of movdqu. There is a slight difference in execution time between these 2 instructions!

Comment: The current i386 System V ABI on Linux [requires 16-byte stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-system-v-amd64-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment).  Not all OSes do that for 32-bit, e.g. I think Windows still only requires 4-byte alignment for 32-bit processes.  You can do `and esp, -16` in a function, though; saving/restoring the original ESP is probably cheaper than a *separate* stack.

Comment: Well, if the OS ensures the 16-byte stack alignment there is no question that you can simply replace the `movdqu` with `movdqa` and everything is fine.
But, if the OS doesn’t require any alignment on stack, even the `and esp, -16` won’t help much as you have to restore anyway the original `esp` after popping the last xmm register.

Comment: Yes, you have to save/restore the old ESP.  But that's no more expensive than maintaining a 2nd stack!  Compilers use `and esp, -16` or `-32` or whatever alignment they require when they have to spill a `__m256`, or if you use `alignas(16)`.  https://godbolt.org/g/6856no.  `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` tells gcc to only use 4-byte stack alignment.  (In 32-bit mode it chooses to use `rep stos` instead of vector stores, but does give the requested alignment.)  The stack-alignment overhead is only once per function (it maybe ties up an extra register, but by hand you can spill that)